# Calcular lexicograficamente letra de uma string

Tags: c, string

Minha função precisa calcular lexicograficamente o valor dos caracteres (pela tabela ASCII) da string. Por exemplo:

> "Alibaba" e "Veio"
> 'A' = 65 e 'V' = 86
> 65 - 86 = -21.

Então a função retornaria `l1` e se fosse igual a primeira iria para a próxima letra. Se todas a letras forem iguais, retornaria 0. Mas ela sempre está retornando `l2`. Estou fazendo o cálculo errado?

Meu código:

```
void str_comparacao(char str1[], char str2[]) 
{   
    int i=0;  
    int y;  

    while(str1[i] != '\0' && str2[i] != '\0')
    {
        while(str1[i] != str2[i])
        {

            if(str1[i]==str2[i])
            {
                y=str1[i]-str2[i];
            }
            i++;    
        }
        i++;
    }

    if(y<0)
    printf("L1, str1 < str2\n");
    else
    printf("L2, str1 > str2\n");

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você percorre as strings apenas uma vez, portanto não faz sentido haver dois laços `while`.

Tudo isso pode ser resolvido com um `for`. Você percorre as duas strings juntas até achar uma letra diferente ou até elas acabarem.

Veja aqui o código resultante:

```
int str_comparacao(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str1[i] == str2[i] && str1[i] != 0; i++) {}
    return str1[i] - str2[i];
}

void teste(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    int resultado = str_comparacao(str1, str2);
    char c = resultado < 0 ? '<' : resultado > 0 ? '>' : '=';
    printf("%s %c %s\n", str1, c, str2);
}

int main() {
    teste("Vermelho", "Verde");
    teste("Verde", "Verde");
    teste("Verde", "Vermelho");
    teste("Verde", "Cinza");
    teste("Cinza", "Verde");
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Vermelho > Verde
Verde = Verde
Verde < Vermelho
Verde > Cinza
Cinza < Verde
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/MvJrbp)

Observe que o `&& str1[i] != 0` só verifica se uma das strings acabou. Isso acontece porque o que está depois do `&&` só será avaliado quando as strings tiverem conteúdo diferentes, e portanto o que está depois do `&&` só será avaliado nos casos onde ou ambas acabaram ou ambas não acabaram. Logo, para detectar o caso onde ambas acabaram, basta verificar uma delas.

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu queria saber como faria isso por letra. Tipo assim, o 'V' de vermelho e verde sao iguais, entao ia pra proxima letra e assim sucessivamente, ate chegar numa letra diferente e calcular a diferenca entre os valores das letras, entendeu?

Comment: @flavio Sim, entendi, e é exatamente isso que esse código faz!

Comment: A é, fiz o exemplo errado kkkk, obrigado mano, ajudou mto <3